# Vuex , recibo " Promise {<pending>} " a la hora de llamar un action de mi store (peticion http)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

estaba intentando hacer una llamada desde un componente a un action de mi vuex pero en el en le response recibo : `Promise {<pending>}` en vez del resultado (que es un json de pruebas).

La llamada del action la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
this.$store.dispatch('propuesta/test');
```

Y esa funcion corresponde a codigo siguiente:

```
export const   PropuestaStore =
    {
        namespaced: true,
        state:{
            test:'Soy PropuestaStore'
        },
        getters:{
            test(state){
                return state.test;
            }
        },
        actions:{
            test(context){
                axios.get('/testing').then(res => {
                   return res;
                }).catch(err => {
                    return err;
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Simplemente quiero guardar la respuesta en algun lado y ya hacer con ella lo que quiera.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo de esta manera, ubicando la petición en un `try/catch` y esperando su respuesta, no estoy seguro de que funcione solo poniendo el `async` y el `await`.

```
export const  PropuestaStore = {
    namespaced: true,
    state:{
        test:'Soy PropuestaStore'
    },
    getters:{
        test(state){
            return state.test;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setData(state, payload) {
            state.test = payload
        }
    }
    actions:{
        async getData() {
            let response;
            try {
                response = await axios.get('/testing');
            } catch (err) => {
                // Hacer algo con el error acá
                return;
            }

            dispatch("setData", response)
        }
    }
}
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Tienes puesto dos 'await' seguidos , me esta dando error y creo que es por eso.

Comment: Perdón, error de tipeo.

Comment: Al final lo que he hecho es no usar Vuex